# ASP.NET Web API routing with action parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

in the WebApiConfig.cs file of my Web API project I have replaced the default routing mapping to this one:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ContActId",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

as I want controller and action combinations instead of a lot of GETs and POSTs.

The problem is this. I have a controller CityController with below 2 actions.

```
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GenderCount()
        {
            //Validate session and fetch gender related data of the city
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, genderData);                
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GenderCount(string cityID)
        {
            //Validate session and fetch gender related data of the city
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, genderData);                
        }
```

The **{HostName}/api/City/GenderCount?cityID=4** API call works but when I try to issue the same API call in the **{HostName}/api/City/GenderCount/4** format, it goes to the without-parameter 'GenderCount()' action.

Comment: m wondering why my code is NOT beautified

Comment: It is unable to map the `id` route parameter. change action parameter from `string cityID` to `string id` or do the reverse and update the route itself.

Comment: @Nkosi your answer worked partly. in the 'reverse' case, the POST actions could not be found with 404 resource not found message. Why did you not put this as the actual answer instead of Comment?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a route prefix

```
[RoutePrefix("api/City")]
```

on your controller, try decorating your method with attribute routing.

```
[Route("GenderCount/{cityID}"]
```

OR

use full route path

```
[Route("api/City/GenderCount/{cityID}")]
```

Comment: The without parameter action method is invoked even after enabling attribute routing and decorating the action, as you advised.

Comment: I have also verified the namespace of the route attribute which is "System.Web.Http".

Comment: It is fixed now. I had to add [Route("api/City/GenderCount/{cityID}")] instead of only [Route("{cityID}")]. If you update your answer accordingly, I can accept it. Probably you assumed that my CityController already has [RoutePrefix("api/City")] linked with it.

Comment: @user1451111 Yes, I assumed that you have RoutePrefix. Edited my answer.